# GTM v5 Android : Auto refresh container

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

How does the gtm container auto refresh works in v5. Can we force refresh the container. Can't find a reference for this.

Comment: Have you had any luck? I am also looking for this.. its seems like a major oversight to remove this functionality.